# Extracting a substring of a period-separated string

Tags: postgresql

I need to get sub string of data float value which looks like

```
eg :32.85.67
   sometimes 32.4.67
```

I need to remove value from second dot in both occurrence(example).

```
Result:32.85 
         32.4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If it has multiple periods it isn't a float at all, it's just a string. Use regular string processing facilities - pattern matching / regular expressions.

eg:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('12.34.56', '\d+\.(\d+)\.\d+'))[1];
```

or:

```
SELECT substring('12.34.56' from '[0-9]+\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+');
```

The latter is probably a bit cleaner as it avoids the 1-element array unpack, and it's more standard.